# Access SQL Query IIF statement Too Complex

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on Access database and writing a query with IFF to output abbreviated states like so

```
IIf(Trim(CtblStates.StateName) = 'New York', 'NY', 
IIf(Trim(CtblStates.StateName) = 'Maryland', 'MD', 
IIf(Trim(CtblStates.StateName) = 'Virginia', 'VA', 
IIf(Trim(CtblStates.StateName) = 'New Jersey', 'NJ', 
IIf(Trim(CtblStates.StateName) = 'District of Columbia', 'DC', 
IIf(Trim(CtblStates.StateName) = 'Florida', 'FL', 
IIf(Trim(CtblStates.StateName) = 'West Virginia', 'WV', 
IIf(Trim(CtblStates.StateName) = 'Georgia', 'GA', 
IIf(Trim(CtblStates.StateName) = 'Alabama', 'AL', 
IIf(Trim(CtblStates.StateName) = 'Alaska', 'AK', 
IIf(Trim(CtblStates.StateName) = 'California', 'CA', 
IIf(Trim(CtblStates.StateName) = 'Pennsylvania', 'PA',
IIf(Trim(CtblStates.StateName) = 'Delaware', 'DE',
CtblStates.StateName  )))))))))))))   AS State,
```

When I try to add more states, I got the 'IFF statement is too complex'. 
I know that you can only add so much IIF statement, but I need to handle
each of the 50 states. How can I get around this?

Thanks

Comment: Add a state table with abbreviation and use it in a join

Comment: I agree with @JohnCappelletti and JNevill has a nice table for you.  If you really can't or don't want to add a table use a SWITCH statement rather than IIF

Answer (score 4):

Just to help make @JohnCappelletti's suggestion easier the SQL to add the new table is below. Then just join it up to your query.

```
CREATE TABLE states (stateName CHAR, stateAbbr CHAR);
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Alabama','AL');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Alaska','AK');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Arizona','AZ');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Arkansas','AR');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('California','CA');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Colorado','CO');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Connecticut','CT');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Delaware','DE');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Florida','FL');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Georgia','GA');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Hawaii','HI');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Idaho','ID');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Illinois','IL');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Indiana','IN');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Iowa','IA');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Kansas','KS');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Kentucky','KY');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Louisiana','LA');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Maine','ME');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Maryland','MD');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Massachusetts','MA');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Michigan','MI');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Minnesota','MN');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Mississippi','MS');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Missouri','MO');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Montana','MT');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Nebraska','NE');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Nevada','NV');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('New Hampshire','NH');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('New Jersey','NJ');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('New Mexico','NM');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('New York','NY');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('North Carolina','NC');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('North Dakota','ND');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Ohio','OH');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Oklahoma','OK');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Oregon','OR');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Pennsylvania','PA');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Rhode Island','RI');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('South Carolina','SC');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('South Dakota','SD');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Tennessee','TN');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Texas','TX');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Utah','UT');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Vermont','VT');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Virginia','VA');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Washington','WA');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('West Virginia','WV');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Wisconsin','WI');
INSERT INTO states (stateName, stateAbbr) VALUES ('Wyoming','WY');
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that!

Use "dictionary table". Add new table to MS Access database. Define 2 columns. One - "FullName" and second - "ShortName". Then add your corresponding values:

```
"New York" | "NY"
"Maryland" | "MD"
```

etc.

Now, use `join`:

```
SELECT a.*, b.ShortName
FROM YourTable As a INNER JOIN DictionaryTable AS b ON a.StateName = b.FullName;
```

Feel free o improve query to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Because the name of your table I think you need to create a new field on table `CtblStates`:

1. Add a new field to table `[CtblStates]` called `State` and fill with the states data according to each row.
2. Replace your query with `[CtblStates].State`